# How to disable a field in edit view using Symfony 2 FormBuilder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I created a form with Symfony2 FormBuilder and I want to disabled one of the fields in the edit view. I'm actually hiding it with a wrapper (`display:none`) but I was wondering if there's a better way to do this. My code looks like the following:

**EntityType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('fieldToDisabledInEditView');
    // ...
```

**EntityController**

```
public function newAction() {
    $entity = new Entity;
    $form = $this->createForm(new EntityType, $entity);
    // ...
}
public function editAction() {
    $entity = new Entity;
    $form = $this->createForm(new EntityType, $entity);
    // ...
}
```

**New (twig) Template**

```
<form>
    {{ form_row(form.fieldToDisabledInEditView) }}
    {# ... #}
```

**Edit (twig) Template**

```
<form>
    <span class="theValueOfTheHiddenField">{{ entity.fieldToDisabledInEditView }}</span>
    <div style="display:none">
        {{ form_row(form.fieldToDisabledInEditView) }}
    </div>
    {# ... #}
```

Comment: I know this is an old question but realise that display: none will still send the value in the form where disabled will not. So you might delete some stuff you don't want to.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you will find that you will have other differences between create and edit, especially validation groups.  Since your controller knows which operation is being done then consider creating two form types EditEntity and CreateEntity and then using a common base to minimize duplicate code.  @cheesemackfly shows how to add a disabled attribute to an element.

But of course you probably feel that having two forms is a waste for such a simple difference.  In which case, add a intention flag to your class and set it in the controller

```
class EntityType
{
    public function __construct($intention)
    {
        $this->intention = $intention;

     ...
    // Use $this->intention to tweak the form

    }
}

// controller
$form = $this->createForm(new EntityType('create'), $entity);
OR
$form = $this->createForm(new EntityType('edit'), $entity);
```

If you really want to get into it then use di to inject the intention.

```
 // controller
 $formType = $this->get('entity.create.formtype');
 OR
 $formType = $this->get('entity.edit.formtype');
```

By using services you can start with just the one formtype and then when you end up splitting it into two (which you will) your controllers will still work as before.

And one more thing, you can actually set the disabled attribute directly in twig assuming you are using different templates for edit/create.  So no code changes at all.

```
{{ form_row(form.yourField, { 'attr':{'disabled':'disabled'} }) }}
```

========================================================================
Update: 03 March 2016

Just in case anybody stumbles across this, be aware the Symfony 3 no longer supports having one class implement multiple form types.  You basically have to have individual form type classes even if they are almost identical.  And never add instance data to your form types.

Comment: Thanks both of you (@cheesemacfly). For now I'm taking only the `{{ form_row(form.yourField, { 'attr':{'disabled':'disabled'} }) }}` part, but is a good to know how to modify the form type without duplicating the forms. Thanks again, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 16):

This is the typical case where you can use an event subscriber to a form class.
In your case, it should be as:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Form/EventListener/AddfieldToDisabledInEditViewSubscriber.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class AddfieldToDisabledInEditViewSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // check if the object is "new"
        // If you didn't pass any data to the form, the data is "null".
        // This should be considered a new object
        if (!$data || !$data->getId()) {
            $form->add('fieldToDisabledInEditView');
        }
        else
        {
            $form->add('fieldToDisabledInEditView', null, array('disabled' => true));
            //If PHP >= 5.4
            //$form->add('fieldToDisabledInEditView', null, ['disabled' => true]);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your form type:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Form/Type/EntityType.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

// ...
use Acme\DemoBundle\Form\EventListener\AddfieldToDisabledInEditViewSubscriber;

class EntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('your_field');
        //...

        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddfieldToDisabledInEditViewSubscriber());
    }

    // ...
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 12):

This approach is not elegant at all but I use it because is simple:

**EntityController**

```
public function newAction() {
    $entity = new Entity;
    $form = $this->createForm(new EntityType, $entity);
    // ...
}
public function editAction() {
    $entity = new Entity;
    $form = $this->createForm(new EntityType, $entity);
    $form->remove('fieldToDisabledInEditView');    
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For those looking for a solution in Symfony 3 without creating separate form type classes (for both add and edit) and without using form events, you can define a custom option and pass it to the form on creation:

I created an `is_edit` option with default value `false` in the form type class:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => SomeEntity::class,
        'is_edit' => false
    ));
}
```

You can access this option using the `$options` array in the `buildForm` method of the same class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('someField', TextType::class, array(
        'disabled' => $options['is_edit']
    ))
}
```

Finally, you can override the default value by passing it on form creation:

```
$someForm = $this->createForm(
    SomeEntityType::class,
    $someEntity,
    array('is_edit' => true)
);
```

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_dependencies.html

Comment: There's a major downside using `disabled` - data from this field will not be sent to the server, and so any error in editable field will clear values in disabled fields. We switched to `attrs['readonly]`

Answer (score 0):

**New (twig) Template** Dont forget {{ form_row(form._token) }} when rendering form fields individualy

```
<form>
    {{ form_row(form.fieldToDisabledInEditView) }}
    {{ form_row(form.field2) }}
    {{ form_row(form.field3) }}
    {# ... #}
    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
```

**Edit (twig) Template** Just don't render {{ form_row(form.fieldToDisabledInEditView) }} and again don't forget token.

```
<form>
    {{ form_row(form.field2) }}
    {{ form_row(form.field3) }}
    {# ... #}
    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
```